# Object with a tilde ('~') property

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am printing out the contents of an object in the console and one of the properties within the object that I notice is an array of strings with `~` as the name of the array (`~:Array[5]`). What does this mean and how do I access it?

Comment: It'd help if you showed what the console output actually looks like, but if there's a property in an object named `"~"` you'd access it with `theObject["~"]`

Comment: We can't tell you what it means when we have no idea what it is. Without further information, it's just that: an oddly named property holding an array of strings.